# Limit delay between form appearance and application of custom form handler

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, forms

I have a working prototype of HTML form working in sidebar inside Google Sheets. Everything works fine if I wait approximately 30 seconds after running the script, otherwise the submit button and the whole form disappears instead.

[image: Screenshot of the google sheets sheet]

As shown on the screenshot, the whole thing is just a simple HTML form with submit button and a picture working as a button. Button is running function `loadSideBar()` and after clicking I have to wait 30 seconds to be able to use the form properly. Otherwise, the whole form disappears and does not write anything into the sheet.

Any chance to remove this wait time?

Code.gs:

```
var sheetName = 'Sheet1'
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()


function onOpen()
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Tools')
    .addItem('createTextEntryForm', 'createTextEntryForm')
    .addToUi();

  loadSideBar();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Menu').addItem('loadSidebar', 'loadSideBar').addToUi();  
}


function intialSetup () {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}

function loadSideBar()
{
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');//sidebar for html and formBar for form
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);

 // doPost ();


}
```

index.html:

```
<form name="submit-to-google-sheet">
  <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
  <input name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
  <input name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
  <BR>
  <BR>
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>

<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/formdata-polyfill"></script>
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/promise-polyfill@latest"></script>
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/whatwg-fetch@latest"></script>

<script>
  const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx0rzbLMsXKQ1C3--qP-wHtcFdfvmOG--y_Qpk0xc43EqtUdSeF/exec'
  const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']

  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
      .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
  })
</script>
```

Comment: The reason for the delay is that the form appears long before your scripts finish loading. Simple solution: don't display the form until you've added your event listener. Better solution: rewrite your HTML to avoid needing to load in external libraries, since they are almost certainly the source of the slow loading.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply and the explanation. any chance you would know any example / similar thread of how to make this work? I am worried this is the best i could do with my basic skills.

Comment: Nevermind i have removed the external scripts for optimalization and it runs much faster now. Thanks for identifying the root cause.